# Is there a Thanksgiving hat?

Tags: temple-run-2

Usually when there is an artifact set introduced, when completing the set, the reward is some kind of hat to wear.  The rings, masks, critters, floral, Christmas, Valentines, St. Patricks, Easter, July 4th and the recent Halloween articacts all follow this pattern..  I collected all the Thanksgiving items but there was no "Congratulations, you have earned a hat, would you like to wear it now?" message as is typical.  Has anyone seen a hat reward for the Thanksgiving artifacts?